# C# sqlConnection class not accepting connection string when passing argument connection string dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a Windows Forms application using SQL Server. I have a connection string config entry (of type `string`) inside the `properties.settings.default` which contains value

```
Data Source=17*.20*.1**.1\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDemoDB;User Id=sa;Password=somepassword
```

If I use

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.connectionString);
sqlCon.open();
```

this will throw an exception that network instance error, go here to view the error screenshot

[screenshot of exception.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtHYw.png)

If I use the connection string directly as the `SqlConnection` argument like this:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection("Data Source=17*.20*.1**.1\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDemoDB;User Id=sa;Password=somepassword");
sqlCon.open();
```

it throws the same exception.

```
SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=17*.20*.1**.1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDemoDB;User Id=sa;Password=somepassword");
sqlCon.open();
```

is also throwing the same exception.

But the below code works fine and connecting to database! I wonder what goes wrong here!

```
string a = "Data Source=17*.20*.1**.1\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDemoDB;User Id=sa;Password=somepassword";

SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(a);
sqlCon.open();
```

Can anyone help me fix this bug? Because the connection string I want to specify from a text file for dynamic changes.

Answer (score 5):

Connection strings that you put in configuration file differ from connection strings that you put in "regular" string literals in that the strings from configuration file do not need to be escaped.

Remove the second slash from the string in your configuration file to fix the problem:

```
connectionString="Source=17*.20*.1**.1\SQLEXPRESS;Database=myDemoDB;User Id=sa;Password=somepassword"
//                                    ^
```

Note that "verbatim" string literals (i.e. ones with `@` prefix) do not require escaping of backslashes, so the connection string would look the same in the config file and in the program.